# How to delete or terminate rows in matlab

Tags: matlab, row, break

hi guys i want to delete or terminate rows containing d>8, here's my code

```
fileID = fopen('d.csv','w');


fprintf(fileID, ' a, b, d \n');
for a = -3:3
   for b= -3:3
           d =  a^2 + b^2;
           if d > 8
               break;
           else
          fprintf(' %d, %d, %d, \n',a,b,d);
           end
    end
end

fclose(fileID);
```

i used break to delete rows, break works only for loop or while loop but it doesn't work in mine, what the output shows are headings, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a **[`vectorized`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html)** approach to get things done faster!? The code listed next could be one such approach that uses a great tool for vectorization - **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** and then writes to output file with another fast I/O writing tool - **[`dlmwrite`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html)** -

```
file = 'results.txt'; %//'# Path to output text or csv file
offset = 3;           %// offset factor used inside the loops
comp = 8;             %// value to be compared against for D

%// Find all possible d values
dvals = bsxfun(@plus,[-offset:offset]'.^2,[-offset:offset].^2) %//'

%// Find a and b values satisfying the comparison criteria
[avals,bvals] = ind2sub(size(dvals),find(dvals <= comp))

%// Write the values to the output file with dlmwrite
dlmwrite(file,' a, b, d ','')
dlmwrite(file,[avals(:)-offset-1 bvals(:)-offset-1 dvals(dvals<=comp)],'-append')
```

Verify results -

```
>> type(file)

 a, b, d 
-2,-2,8
-1,-2,5
0,-2,4
1,-2,5
2,-2,8
-2,-1,5
-1,-1,2
0,-1,1
1,-1,2
2,-1,5
-2,0,4
-1,0,1
0,0,0
1,0,1
2,0,4
-2,1,5
-1,1,2
0,1,1
1,1,2
2,1,5
-2,2,8
-1,2,5
0,2,4
1,2,5
2,2,8
```

---

**For-loop code for newbies -**

```
fprintf(fileID, ' a, b, d \n');
for a = -3:3
    for b= -3:3
        d =  a^2 + b^2;
        if d <= 8
            fprintf(fileID,' %d, %d, %d, \n',a,b,d);
        end
    end
end
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: yeah your syntax works, but much complex, and i think it have limitations, so there's no way deleting or terminating rows from my code?

Comment: @matlabnewbie Can't think of "limitations", but yeah I guess not easy to follow `bsxfun` when you are starting off into MATLAB. Check out the edited codes at the end?